# jQuery - Find an integer value in a table row and alert the first column of the row

Tags: jquery

I have already searched for my question on SO and on other media, but I can not find a working solution for this.

All I need is to find a value (5 or greater) in a column, and then alert the value of the first column of that row.

I am very new to jQuery, so the solution may actually be simple, but I can't figure it out.

This is my table layout:

```
<tr class="itemRow row-0 odd" id="cartItem_SCI-1">

<td class="item-name"> Hat - Spring Collection </td>

<td class="item-price">$20.00</td>

<td class="item-decrement"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_decrement">-</a></td>

<td class="item-quantity">1</td>

<td class="item-increment"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_increment">+</a></td>

<td class="item-total">$20.00</td><td class="item-remove"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove">Remove</a></td></tr>
```

What I wanted to do is find if item-quantity is equal or greater than 5 and then alert item-name based on that.

Comment: If I am correct, either if item-total is 5 or greater or if item-quantity is 5 of greater, alert item-name?

Comment: 5 or greater value for item-price or item-total?

Comment: I don't get it, on your example, you need to find the first cell of the row with an integer value (20.00) and alert... what ? can you told us what you want to do exactly (not in "column" but in "price" language)

Comment: I am sorry for not wording my question properly, should have proof read it again. What I wanted to do is find if item-quantity is equal or greater than 5 and then alert item-name based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alboy51/2bzupmd0/)

Loop through all rows, convert all money values to number and do a check on them. If greater than 5, find the row's name `<td>` and alert it.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.itemRow').each(function(){
        var itemprice = $(this).find('.item-price').html();
        var itemprice_format = Number( itemprice.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
        if(itemprice_format >= 5)
            alert($(this).parent().find('.item-name').html());
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr class="itemRow row-0 odd" id="cartItem_SCI-1">
        <td class="item-name"> Hat - Spring Collection1 </td>
        <td class="item-price">$4.00</td>
        <td class="item-decrement"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_decrement">-</a></td><td class="item-quantity">1</td>
        <td class="item-increment"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_increment">+</a></td>
        <td class="item-total">$20.00</td><td class="item-remove"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="itemRow row-0 odd" id="cartItem_SCI-2">
        <td class="item-name"> Hat - Spring Collection2 </td>
        <td class="item-price">$20.00</td>
        <td class="item-decrement"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_decrement">-</a></td><td class="item-quantity">1</td>
        <td class="item-increment"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_increment">+</a></td>
        <td class="item-total">$10.00</td><td class="item-remove"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I needed, thank you very much. But there seems to be an error in which case it always alerts the name of the first row, no matter in which row the value was found, do you know what causes this?

Comment: Are you sure? Check the Fiddle I provided. If you increase the price of the first row, it alerts first and second row. Try it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2bzupmd0/4/

I modified your fiddle a bit.

I didn't word my question properly, but I changed it as to suit my needs and it works, but it always alerts the name in the first row, even if the number 5 is found in the second row.

I really appreciate your time and I do not wish to waste it, but I don't know where else to turn for help.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/alboy51/2bzupmd0/6/
Found the mistake. Had to remove .parent() from the alert() function. I was pointing to the table, not to the row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can iterate all `tr`s using `.each()` and compare price and total values if greater or equal to 5 then show `item-name` in `alert()`

```
$(function(){
    $('#tableId tr').each(function(){
       var itemPrice = parseFloat($(this).find('.item-price').text()) || 0;
       var itemTotal = parseFloat($(this).find('.item-total').text()) || 0;
       if(itemPrice >= 5 || itemTotal >= 5)
          alert($(this).find('.item-name').text());
    });
});
```